# Pandas IndexError: list index out of range while dealing with multiple level files

Tags: python, pandas

I've a functions that loads json files and constructs a pandas DataFrame. Most of the files has just one level, however, some of them have more, two or three levels of data as in these example files attached here. I'm would like to deal with it while processing these files, but I'm always stopped by `IndexError: list index out of range`. How could I fix it?

```
def fetchFromJson(path):

    json_files = [pos_json for pos_json in os.listdir(path) if pos_json.endswith('.json')]
    
    data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'cod', 'tema'])
    # we need both the json and an index number so use enumerate()
    for index, js in enumerate(json_files):
        with open(os.path.join(path, js)) as json_file:
            json_text = json.load(json_file)

            id = re.search(r'(\d+).json', js).group(1)
            cod = json_text['dados'][0]['codTema']
            tema = json_text['dados'][0]['tema']
        
            # push a list of data into a pandas DataFrame at row given by 'index'
            data.loc[index] = [id, cod, tema]
        
    return data
```

One-level files :

```
 {"dados": [{"codTema": 46, "tema": "Educacao", "relevancia": 0}], "links": [{"rel": "self", "href": "https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/proposicoes/101424/temas"}]}
```

Two-level files :

```
{"dados": [{"codTema": 64, "tema": "Agricultura, Pecuaria, Pesca e Extrativismo", "relevancia": 0}, {"codTema": 58, "tema": "Trabalho e Emprego", "relevancia": 0}], "links": [{"rel": "self", "href": "https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/proposicoes/101425/temas"}]}
```

Comment: Do not use [`id`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) *(or any other name of built-in function)* as a name of variable.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Please include the full stack trace into your question.